# How to set the initial centroids of KMColourSegmenter in OpenIMAJ library?

Tags: java, image-processing, k-means, image-segmentation, openimaj

I want to measure the time that KMColourSegmenter, in OpenIMAJ library, takes to perform the clustering.

If I didn't make the initial centroids fixed, rather than random, I can't make the measure the performance; because it will change every time, give different number of iterations , and vary in time to execute the clustering.

So how to make the initial centroids fixed i.e. setting them manually?

**Update:**

@Jon Thanks for the answer, I am trying to implement what you said. Could you check it, especially the "clusters" array I think this array doesn't make sense to initialize. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

```
public class MyFloatKMeansInit extends FloatKMeansInit{

    @Override
    public void initKMeans(DataSource<float[]> bds, float[][] clusters) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < bds.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bds.getData(i).length; j++) {
                clusters[i][j]=bds.getData(i)[j];
            }
        }   
    }
}

public class MyKMColourSegmenter extends KMColourSegmenter{

    public MyKMColourSegmenter(FloatArrayBackedDataSource bds, ColourSpace colourSpace, int K) throws IOException {
        super(colourSpace, K);
        MyFloatKMeansInit myFloatKMeansInit = new MyFloatKMeansInit();
        float[][] clusters = new float[K][];//#######I think there is something wrong here
        myFloatKMeansInit.initKMeans(bds, clusters);
        this.kmeans.setInit(myFloatKMeansInit);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to implement this yourself; create a subclass of `KMColourSegmenter` and create a constructor that takes in the centroids, as well as any parameters needed by your choice of constructor in the `KMColourSegmenter` super class. Then in your constructor, after the call to `super`, use the `this.kmeans.setInit()` method to set a initialisation to use you predefined centroids. You'll need to implement a custom `FloatKMeansInit` subclass that lets you set the centroids externally, but this should be trivial as it only requires implementing a single method.

**Update in response to amended question:**

You shouldn't call `initKMeans` directly; that happens behind the scenes when you run the algorithm. You also need to populate the centroids array with the centroids initial centroids you want rather than from the `bds`. For example (untested):

```
public class MyFloatKMeansInit extends FloatKMeansInit{
    private float [][] mycentroids;

    public MyFloatKMeansInit(float [][] mycentroids) {//modifying data type here
        this.mycentroids = mycentroids;
    }

    @Override
    public void initKMeans(DataSource<float[]> bds, float[][] clusters) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < mycentroids.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mycentroids[i].length; j++) {
                clusters[i][j]=mycentroids[i][j]; //could use arraycopy instead
            }
        }   
    }
}

public class MyKMColourSegmenter extends KMColourSegmenter{

    public MyKMColourSegmenter(ColourSpace colourSpace, float[][] mycentroids) throws IOException {
        super(colourSpace, mycentroids.length);
        MyFloatKMeansInit myFloatKMeansInit = new MyFloatKMeansInit(mycentroids);
        this.kmeans.setInit(myFloatKMeansInit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jon that worked. Is there a way to know how many iterations the algorithm takes till converge?

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at it.